# Conflict between includes: stdafx.h and <vector> VisualStudio 2012 C++ (error C2953: class template has already been defined)

Tags: c++, include, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2012

I've been stuck on this problem for too long, and must ask the almighty Stack. Please forgive the simplicity of the issue!

I am working on the BowlingGame kata in VisualStudio 2012 in order to practice their version of unit tests. I'm in the middle of the refactoring section of Test #2, where I add a vector to my Game class in order to save the number of pins rolled.

When I added the vector include to my header, however, I got a compiler error! In fact, it's my unit test class that is throwing the compiler error (not my source code).

I believe the issue is a conflict between the stdafx.h include in the unit test class and the vector include in the source code header, but I'm not sure. It could also be a managed/native C++ issue? I've had to work through a few of those during this exercise.

Below is the compiler error (abbreviated, as it just goes on and on) and the code for my three files so far. Please let me know what I can do to get past this issue. I am trying to use "best practices" for this exercise, so if you see anything else that looks fishy, please do let me know!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BowlingGameUnitTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.7.21 Windows License 7978 
1>  Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2012
1>CL : Command line warning d9999: changing /clr:safe to -clr
1>  BowlingGameTest.cpp
1>c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include/xrefwrap(156): warning C4561: '__fastcall' incompatible with the '/clr' option: converting to '__stdcall'
1>c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include/xrefwrap(156): error C2953: 'std::_Result_of<_Ret(__stdcall &)(void),std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' : class template has already been defined
1>          c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include/xrefwrap(156) : see declaration of 'std::_Result_of<_Ret(__stdcall &)(void),std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>'
1>c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include/xrefwrap(156): error C2953: 'std::_Result_of<_Ret(__stdcall *)(void),std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' : class template has already been defined
1>          c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include/xrefwrap(156) : see declaration of 'std::_Result_of<_Ret(__stdcall *)(void),std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>'
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
    Game(void);
    ~Game(void);
    void roll( int pins );
    int score();

private:
    int totalScore;
    vector<int> rolls;
    int currentRoll;
};
```

Game.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(void)
{
    totalScore = 0;
    currentRoll = 0;
}

Game::~Game( void )
{
}

void Game::roll( int pins )
{
    totalScore += pins;
    rolls.push_back(pins);
}

int Game::score()
{
    return totalScore;
}
```

BowlingGameTest.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../BowlingGame/Game.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

namespace BowlingGameUnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public ref class BowlingGameTest
    {
    private:
        Game* game;

    public: 
        [TestInitialize()]
        void MyTestInitialize() 
        {
            game = new Game();
        }

        void rollMany( int frames, int pins ) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            {
                game->roll(pins);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        void gutterGame()
        {
            rollMany(20, 0);
            Assert::AreEqual<int>(0, game->score());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        void testAllOnes()
        {
            rollMany(20, 1);
            Assert::AreEqual<int>(20, game->score());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the using namespace and instead fully qualify your namespace calls?

Comment: Is this a C++/CLI project (it looks as such from your compiler output). If so I am pretty sure you can't use std::vector, instead you would need to use the [cliext vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386284.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, changing from std::vector to cliext vector is giving me more mananged vs. unmanaged errors. I'm wondering if I perhaps set up my Solution incorrectly (or the hard way)? I have a "Win32 Project" with a "Managed Test Project."

Comment: That is the probably the issue. If you can make your "game" class produce a dll, then have the test project include the reference you may be able to work around it, but its probably going to be a battle to get it working.  On the other hand, if you are using VS2012, they have built in support for C++ unit testing. Then you can use the std::vector and don't get into issues of trying to compile your code as both managed and unmanaged.

Comment: I'll start over with a fresh Solution using these [instructions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx) Wish me luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to pstrjds!

Answer part 1: Change std::vector to cliext vector, as my unit test project is a C++/CLI project.

Answer part 2: Reconfigure the Solution. Currently, it's native source and managed unit tests, but that causes lots of niggly issues. Will change to native source and native unit tests.